# Android 5.0 only - UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: android, native, unsatisfiedlinkerror, s5

We've got a very odd problem. Our native app is throwing an "UnsatisfiedLinkError" for any native call we make - But only on Android 5.0 and only on the Galaxy S5. The app works fine on all other devices, but only exhibits this crash on this device (It's been downloaded nearly 1 million times).

The app has a native activity, so the library load isn't the problem (the app runs natively for a while until the first java->native call).

The RegisterNatives returns 0 (success). But as soon as the native callbacks fire, the app barfs with:

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for void com.rubicon.dev.NativeActivity.Adverts_InterstitialFinished(int) (tried Java_com_rubicon_dev_NativeActivity_Adverts_1InterstitialFinished and Java_com_rubicon_dev_NativeActivity_Adverts_1InterstitialFinished__I)

(The interstitial failing is the first callback to fire, this is correct).

Anyone come across this?

More Info:

After much more scratching around:

Our Java app:

OurEngineNativeActivity extends NativeActivity
{
   natives...dont work.
}

OurGameActivity extends OurEngineNativeActivity
{
   natives...work correctly.
}

(This all works fine on Android < 5.0)

When registering natives I register app natives using the GetObjectClass() - These work.

When registering natives for the engine, I use FindClass, which returns a class, no errors or warnings occur.

Calling any of the engine natives give the link error.

If I make all the calls to regiserNatives use the GetObjectClass, it works perfectly on Android >5.0 only, crashes on < 5.0

Completely confused.

Steve.

Comment: Can you post your Make files?

Comment: Hi there, not really as it's build using the Tegra Visual Studio tools. I know that's not really helpful is it? 

Wondering if there's a Java way I can tell if the 'native' calls have been bound correctly.

Comment: Did you not right the JNI Native activity that you mentioned in your post? Dont you have a JNI and makefiles for that?

Comment: Yeah, got the code. No makefiles involved, just Visual Studio projects. All the settings are within the project->properties.

Comment: I am guessing you didnt work on the JNI part? Are you using: https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-nsight-tegra? Search your project, do you not see a `Android.mk` and/or `Application.mk`?

Comment: I didn't set up the original project, correct. Looking for *.mk only reveals the makefile for the static lib. I've just filled it with jibberish, it's not being used. Yeah we're using that tool set. Aren't the settings derived from the project settings?

Comment: I am not sure. I am not familiar with it at all. I looked it as soon as you mentioned it in your previous comment. What do you mean the file is filled with gibberish? The libs was using in my JNI project, I had to change from `shared` to `static`. But the final lib 'module' was `shared`. If you had the `*.mk` filled out, I could be of more help.

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was, I checked to see if the makefile was being used at all by filling it with random text (in fact I renamed it in the end). It wasn't being used.

Here's how it's set up.
Our engine (Raz0r) - compiles to a static lib (.a)
Our app compiles to an .so (actually a final apk) this links in the static lib.

Works a charm apart from S5 with Android 5.0, which makes up 100% of our 'non-spurious' crashes on Google Play.

Comment: I have a similar setup but I had to move to that setup in order to get it to work on Android 5.0. I am not sure how else to configure your project without using the *.mk files